# How can I get volume information from a lower timeframe?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I need to get the volume information from a lower timeframe the same way as the standard VPFR indicator does.

[image: VPFR]

This is 5 minutes timeframe, but it is clearly seen that the standard VPFR uses volume information from a lower timeframe (1 minute I guess)

But when I use `request.security` and attempt to populate an array that was declared at the outer scope, it receives volume information from the current timeframe.

```
var l = array.new_float(0)

test() => 
    array.push(l, volume)    
    volume
    

m_volume = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "1", test(), barmerge.gaps_on, barmerge.lookahead_off)
label.new(time, labelPrice, str.tostring(array.get(l, bar_index)), xloc = xloc.bar_time)
plot(m_volume)
```

The plot shows the volume of the first candle out of a group of 5.
I assumed that the array will be populated with the same values, but instead it receives a full 5m volume. Why?

[image]

Comment: I posted a 'why' this isn't working, but if you ever found a solution please let us know.

Answer (score 0):

> ..instead it receives a full 5m volume. Why?

I believe it's *not* using the lower time frame, it's staying at 5m. I independently produced exactly the same issue on 1h vs 1m.

TradingView doesn't seem to support (and at bare minimum doesn't recommend) retrieving lower time frame data from a higher time frame.

https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Context_switching_the_security_function.html#requesting-data-of-a-lower-timeframe

Answer (score 0):

From the [Pine Script v5 manual](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Other_timeframes_and_data.html#request-security-lower-tf) (the solution is available in v5)

> The request.security() function was designed to request data of a timeframe higher than the current chart timeframe....If you were to use the request.security() function in our example you would actually only get the final minute bar for the last hour since barmerge.lookahead_off is the default. If you were to use barmerge.lookahead_on then you would get the first minute bar instead.

For this purpose there is the [request.security_lower_tf()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_request%7Bdot%7Dsecurity_lower_tf) function. Note that this might provide you [misleading results](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/faq/Other_data_and_timeframes.html?highlight=lower%20timeframe#why-do-intraday-ohlcv-values-not-correspond-to-values-retrieved-with-security-at-daily-timeframes-and-higher) sometimes, but that's the way to use lower tf data on our chart.